# Lucky Bacup Question

Tags: backup

If I have the courage to read the umpteen pages on their site I may find the answer but it's far easier to ask a Lucky Backup user!!
Does Lucky Backup do incremental backups or full backups after the first backup?
I've now just (hopefully) set it to backup once a week. Will it then do another complete backup or simply add the changes since its' last backup?
Thanks
Garoolgan

Comment: Providing your OS & release details maybe helpful, but note Lucky Backup is no longer maintained according to the duplicate page I referred to, so don't forget to consider than when deciding what to use for your *unstated* release.

Answer (score 2):

I use LuckyBackup for a weekly backup of files on my system and have done so through versions 16.04, 18.04 and currently 20.04.

Whilst it is correct to say that there has been no further development on this tool for some time, it is basically a front end for Rsync which remains a superb tool for backing up systems.

> Will it then do another complete backup or simply add the changes
> since its' last backup?

It will trawl through the selected list and only re-backup files where the file has changed.

So the first time of using,it can take some time to run but subsequent runs where files have not changed will mean a much faster run.

Comment: Thanks, just what I wanted to know - garoolgan

Comment: Perhaps you would consider accepting the answer in that case. Thank you.

Comment: Sorry I was as usual doing several things at once!

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/help/someone-answers